# declaration problem in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

Declare a Nullable variable

e.g int? a = null; - This is true that a is having null value by default

declare another variable

```
int b;
b=a; // cannot convert from int? to int error
```

Main Point :-
if a is not having value than null to be passed to b

Point :- How you can get null value in b, do not convert int b to int? b - except this

I need this solution ...anyone can help

Is there any solution

Comment: b is not nullable, so you can't assign a null value to b. And please format your code.

Comment: You have declared `b` as `int` - that means it *can't* hold `null`. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 5):

`b` is of the data type `int` which is a value type.

By definition, an `int` can not be assigned the value null.

If you cannot change `b` to `int?`, then you'll have to decide on another marker to carry the same meaning that you have in mind for `null`.

```
int b = a ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`b` is a value type and can't take a null. That's why you have nullable types...

Answer (score 1):

If you want b to be able to take a null then it also needs to be nullable..

```
int? a = null;
int? b = a;

int c = b.GetValueOrDefault();
bool hasValue= b.HasValue;


int e = hasValue ? b.Value : 0;
```

etc...